# LEGO Plastic Bags #

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, lego-group, set-numbering

[image: 2,4-319g7,5-419g7,7-219g7]
Please help to identify the LEGO Plastic Bags # (2,4-319g7,5-419g7,7-219g7)
I used QR code reader and it gives me a digits of 6172090.
Unfortunately I could not find any information.
I bought this items only in LEGO plastic bags with no other info. from a recycle store.
Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a part number of LEGO. Its also 7 digits long similar what LEGO uses for their parts. As far I know there is no publicly tracked list of these numbers. Best to do is keep the bags closed and post some clear photo's on this site, showing the content of each bag.

Comment: Interestingly, Bag 11 of the Bugatti is 617-2090 on a QR Code reader.

Comment: I believe QR codes can only be used by TLG to identify which polybag should go to certain set during production. So far none of existing QR codes have lead to identification of the set. This means having a QR code or its value is a bit useless.

Answer (score 5):

If the parts on the background are from the bags its probably:

[70614-1: Lightning Jet](https://brickset.com/sets/70614-1/Lightning-Jet)

based on:

[370223: Technic Brick 1X8](https://brickset.com/parts/370223/technic-brick-1x8) in Bright Blue. This is the only set released after 2017 with this part.

It also contains:

[302126: Plate 2X3](https://brickset.com/parts/302126/plate-2x3) in Black

[428623: Roof Tile 1X3/25°](https://brickset.com/parts/428623/roof-tile-1x3-25%C2%B0) in bright blue

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answers joost and you are correct it is the 70614-1/Lightning-Jet. I got the manual after you provide the info, unfortunately sa bags are incomplete... lacking of bags#1,3,6 and did tried to assemble them. I just modify I can from whats left of it. again thanks a lot....allan

Answer (score -1):

Everything Lego does carries an SKU (Stock Keeping Unit).

If you look at most recent instructions, you have a list of parts with 7 digits numbers, that's the part SKU.

Similarly, each set has an SKU (labeled as "item number" next to the EAN / UPC barcode on the box), the box itself has an SKU (written smaller, generally) each instruction / pamphlet has one or more SKU (depending on version) and thus each bag in the box has it's own.

Also recent boxes have, next to the product barcode, a small white box, which appears to contain a lot numbers and production serial numbers which is readable as a datamatrix).

Answer (score -1):

Bag 20 (scan with QR and the note is 6172090) is the spare pieces for the Harry Potter collection (with hedwig standing on a stack of books). It's so you can make the scarf whichever house colour you want.

Comment: This is incorrect. The correct set has already been identified, see the top-rated Answer from nearly 5 years ago.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/12267)

Comment: The QR code on the bag only identifies the plastic bag as the packaging material, and bears no information about its contents.