# Lego Set number or building instructions - lots of lime green and purple and grey

Tags: set-identification

Please help me to identify what is set number for these LEGO sets. I bought them from OP shop but I can’t find what is set number. I just know plastic bag with QR Code and when I scan it becomes 6172090, 2017 The Lego Group

- Plastic bag #2 219g8
- Plastic bag #5 219g8
- Plastic bag #4 319g8[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: It is well known that the numbers on the bags cannot be used to identify the sets; please post images of the bags, with as many pieces visible as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/11276/lego-plastic-bags ?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks so much for your prompt reply. I just edit the question by adding more photos please have a look and help

Comment: Hi everyone I have found the set number. It’s Lego set 41346 Lego Friends Friendship Box.

Answer (score 5):

There are also parts from [10188: Death Star](https://brickset.com/sets/10188-1/Death-Star)

Photo #3 & 4

- [Part # 55236 : Reddish Brown Plant Vine Seaweed / Appendage Spiked / Bionicle Spine](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=55236#T=C)
- [Part# 2585 : Light Bluish Gray String Reel 2 x 2 Drum](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2585&idColor=86#T=C&C=86)
- [Part #30376 : White Legs Mechanical, Battle Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30376&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)
  from [Assassin Droid (White)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=sw0215)
- [Part# 30562 :    Dark Bluish Gray Cylinder Quarter 4 x 4 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30562&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)

Comment: I'm reminded of <https://www.brothers-brick.com/2015/05/04/lego-death-star-remake-in-the-friends-theme/>

Answer (score 1):

@HuongNguyen says it's

> Lego set 41346 Lego Friends Friendship Box

but I just wanted this question to stop coming up as unanswered. Don't upvote it.

Comment: But I just noticed there's also a weapon in there - that is **not** part of the set.